# "I hope this email finds you well"

Tags: verbs, subjunctives, present-subjunctive

Check the following sentence

> I hope this email finds you well

Isn't it expressing a desire and therefore find should be in the subjunctive mood and therefore drop the third person "s"?

I translated it  from Spanish, my native language, where the verb find is in the subjunctive mood.

Comment: We don't really use "hope" in the subjunctive mood in English!  I'm not sure if there is a good reason for this, hopefully someone will know the answer if there is!